What is the meaning of "readers of the interest"?
I was reading a mathematics books and found this sentence:

We believe that there is no better way to convince our readers of the interest and
applicability of certain mathematical ideas or techniques than to show the type
of practical problems and situations that can be tackled, and eventually solved,
by using them.

I'm wondering what does "readers of the interest" mean in this context? I looked up the meaning of interest in Longman dictionary and found:


[uncountable] a quality or feature of something that attracts your attention or makes you want to know more about it.

be of (no) interest (to somebody) (=be interesting or not interesting to someone)
It’s a book that will be of interest to a wide range of readers.
What you do in your private life is of no interest to me.
art galleries, museums and other places of interest
topics of general interest (=that everyone wants to know about)

Does that mean the author is interested in the readers in other words, the readers are interesting to the author?

You are parsing this incorrectly. The phrase "of the interest" does not modify "readers".  The writers want the readers to be convinced that certain mathematical ideas have interest and applicability.

Yes - convince our readers/ of the interest and applicability/ of certain mathematical ideas or techniques

@CanadianYankee Oh thanks for pointing out.

In this case "of the interest" is the object of "convince". Consider, "readers will be convinced of the interest", which will be understood to have the same meaning by many English speakers.
